# How to save the changes when the type is input in rest_in_place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm using the [rest_in_place](https://github.com/janv/rest_in_place) in my rails project, which allowed me to edit the data dynamically.

```
<ul class="offer-completed__edit-details" data-url="<%= enquiry_path(@enquiry) %>" data-object="enquiry">
    <li>Contact Name: <span class="rest-in-place" data-attribute="name"><%= @enquiry.name %></span> <%= link_to "Edit", "#", class: "edit" %></li>
</ul>
```

It will generate a form with `input` tag. However, when I changed the data, only `enter` would save the data. If I lost the focus, the data won't be saved.

I checked at the source code and found [this](https://github.com/janv/rest_in_place/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/rest_in_place/rest_in_place.js.coffee.erb#L213):

```
  "input" :
    activateForm : ->
      value = $.trim(@elementHTML())
      ...
      @$element.find("input").blur => @abort()
```

It means when the form type is `input`, it sets the `blur` to abort, not `update`. For the type `textarea`, it will update when `blur`.

My question is, is there any method to let the input `update` when `blur`(lose focus)?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What if you copy the gem's `lib/assets/javascripts/rest_in_place/rest_in_place.coffee.erb` file to you projects `lib/assets/javascripts/rest_in_place/rest_in_place.coffee.erb` folder and change the method you want.

I'm thinking that will take precedence over the actual method in the gem file. However the downside it, if the code is updated, you may not get the latest changes/functionality